# Reportlab: linking from canvas to internal platypus tag

Tags: python, reportlab

I can easily do links within the main body of my Platypus document, using  and  tags within paragraph objects.

I have a header that uses canvas, though (because it's a two-pass afterFlowable deal), and I want to put a link in the header to one of the  anchor tags defined in a Platypus. Is there a way to do that?